# Odoo custom module don't appear

Tags: python, odoo

I'm new to Odoo and I've created a new folder "custom_addons" in Odoo folder. Inside of that, I've created a folder with the name of my module "gen_doc" with the files `__init__.py` and `__manifest__.py`. There is my code:

**manifest**.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Part of Odoo. See LICENSE file for full copyright and licensing details.

{
   'name': 'Document Generator',
   'version': '1.0',
   'summary': 'Employee Document Generator',
   'sequence': -50,
   'description': """Employee Document Generator""",
   'author': 'Mendim',
   'company': 'HEC',
   'website':'',
   'license': 'LGPL-3',
   'category': 'Management Employee',
   'depends':[
    
    ],
    'data':[

    ],
    'application': True,
}
```

I have added the custom_addons path in the conf file but when I restart Odoo and update the list I'm not seeing my module. It's like nothing is happening. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems your code looks good. Can you share your conf file in your question?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I can't explain why but when i decided to restart my computer it worked maybe it was a bug idk. I'm seeing it now :)

Answer (score 1):

For adding a new module you should do these steps:

1. Build your module with your written code or scaffold command.
2. Add the module path in your config file at addons-path = '',''
3. Change your URL like this: http://localhost:8091/web?debug=1 for setting debug mode true
4. Go to apps and from up tabs
5. Select update app list and refresh your page.
6. Now you can see your module in the apps.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I can't explain why but when i decided to restart my computer it worked maybe it was a bug idk. I'm seeing it now :)